# NSConstraints for placing view at the top when including a navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview, nslayoutconstraint

Various answers to this are on Stack Overflow, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I want a `UIPickerView` to have a width equal to 90 % of the superview's frame width, a height to be 35 % of superview's
frame height, centred horizontally
**and to have it's top equal to the top of the superview but below the navigation bar (this last constraint is what I'm having difficulty with)**.

At the moment, the top of the picker view seems to be behind the navigation bar. I've tried adding `edgesForExtendedLayout = .Top` and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false` so that the picker view is under the navigation bar. I've also tried adding a constant to the constraint 
`NSLayoutConstraint(item: somePickerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .TopMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)` but this didn't move the picker view enough.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let superview = self.view

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        edgesForExtendedLayout = .Top
        extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false

        somePickerView = UIPickerView()
        somePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        superview.addSubview(somePickerView)

        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: somePickerView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: superview.frame.width * 0.90))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: somePickerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: superview.frame.height * 0.35))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: somePickerView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        // the following constraint's not working as expected:
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: somePickerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .TopMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    }
}
```

any advice for the constraint to place the picker view at the top but below the navigation bar?

Comment: Please consider adding some formatting to your question text (paragraphs etc.) because it's difficult to see what it is you are actually asking here.

Comment: How do you center vertically and pin to the top? Also, is the "superview" you are talking about the view controller's view?

Comment: TroyT yes the superview is self.view of the view controller (the code is executed in the viewDidLoad method). The constraints are in the code above: .CenterX, .CenterY and .Top.